# get value by id link with the href

Tags: php, html, href

this is my input

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" />
```

this is my href link

```
<a href="UserOrderProduct.php?id=<?php echo $Pid; ?>
&price=<?php echo $Price; ?>&quantity=">add</a>
```

how to write it in the href and please ignore the

```
<?php echo $Pid; ?>&price=<?php echo $Price; ?>
```

this is because i get the id already from the database but only the quantity not really how to get it, can teach me?

Comment: you want id, price, quantity in URL?

Comment: only for the quantity, because i already get  the id and price

Comment: how you get id , price use the same way for quantity .

Comment: the id and the price i get from the database so that i use to echo them but the quantity no

Comment: You want to know how you get the quantity value from your html form?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Yes and put inside the `<a href=.......quantity=???>` so that i can get them in another page

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form where you get the "quantity" value as it looks from your code:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" />
```

if you use the "GET" method

```
<FORM method='get' action='next_script.php'>
```

all the values will be in the address, otherwise, if you POST the values you'll get them in the next script via $_POST array.

If you need to pass one or more couples variable=value between different scripts the best solution is to use PHP sessions.

You just need to add at the beginning of each script:

```
session_start();
```

and put your_variable and your_value as:

```
$_SESSION['your_variable'] = your_value;
```

or

```
$_SESSION['session_variable'] = $your_variable;
```

In such a way data are not visible on the link and you can access them anywhere you like provided that you keep the session_start() command at the beginning of each php page.

Comment: "if you use the "GET" method all the values will be in the address". You may fetch that value by using $_GET instead of $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

If you have html...

```
<form method="post" action="phpfile.php"> 
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

...in your phpfile.php you can retrieve the value of quantity like this:

```
<?php
$qty = $_POST['quantity'];
?>
<a href="UserOrderProduct.php?id=<?php echo $Pid; ?>
&price=<?php echo $Price; ?>&quantity=<?php echo $qty;?>">add</a>
```